# How add a QR bar code in pdfjet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf, pdf-generation, qr-code

I don´t know how add a QR code on my PDF, i use java and PDFjet, some one can help me????? I use PDFJet because I can´t use Jreports on GAE.

I try this but return error:

```
      QRCode qr = new QRCode("123456", 1);
        qr.setPosition(0, 0);
        qr.drawOn(page);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answere:

```
QRCode qr = new QRCode("123456", ErrorCorrectLevel.H);
qr.setPosition(0, 0);
qr.drawOn(page);
```

only change the second parameter for the type of ErrorCorrectLevel